# React Form - Show Message if Successfully entered into (MongoDB) Database

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, action

I'm sorry I'm sure this question has been answered before I did a few searches and couldn't find it.

I just am trying to figure out a way to submit a form , and get a "Successfully Submitted your information" response to the user, and clear the form.

I made a small form to make it simple - any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit - At the moment you click submit and everything submits into the MongoDB correctly but nothing happens on the Client side. Would like something to show that the data has indeed been added

form.js Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addItem } from '../actions/itemActions';

class Register extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newItem = {
     name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email
   };

  this.props.addItem(newItem);

  this.setState({
  name: "",
  email: ""
  });

 };

 render() {
   return (
      <div>

        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
          <Label for="item">Name</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              id="item"
              placeholder="Full Name"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <Label for="email">Email</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              id="item"
              placeholder="Email"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <Button color="dark" style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }} block>
              Register
               </Button>
              </FormGroup>
           </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addItem }
)(Register);
```

ItemActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING } from './types';

export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setItemsLoading());
  axios.get('/api/items').then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ITEMS,
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};

export const addItem = item => dispatch => {
  axios.post('/api/items', item).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_ITEM,
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};

/* If I wanted to include a delete item request

export const deleteItem = id => dispatch => {
  axios.delete(`/api/items/${id}`).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_ITEM,
      payload: id
    })
  );
};*/

export const setItemsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: ITEMS_LOADING
  };
};
```

items.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Item Model
const Item = require('../../models/Items');

// route   GET api/items
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Item.find()
    .sort({ name: 1 })
    .then(items => res.json(items));
});

// route   POST api/items
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email
  });

  newItem.save();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you are having? What happens right now when you submit the form?

Comment: Right now it submits everything correctly to the MongoDB , on the client side they click and it looks as if nothing is happening.

Comment: Made edits on what the form is currently doing on submit